# RPushbullet, Amazon S3, and Windows

Tags: r, ssl, curl, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When using the package `rpushbullet`, I am unable to push a file from within R.  `RPushbullet` uses `curl` to interact with the Pushbullet API.  Whenever I attempt to push a file, I receive an error code of 60. I believe, from my researching the topic, that this is due to either an improper certificate or an unnecessary SSL connection.

I am able to push notes to the devices on my account so I do know my communication via Pushbullet's API is functioning properly.

Is there a way for me to tell R to include the `-k` option to remove the need for a certificate?